# How to print without newline or space with arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code that takes a crypto coin signal, filters everything I'm not interested in and extracts the coin

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf('1820496713:');
const regex = /#\w+\//g;

const helpMessage = `
Say something to me
/start - start the bot
/help - command reference
`;

bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("Hi I am echoo bot");
    ctx.reply(helpMessage);
})

bot.help((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(helpMessage)
})

bot.on("text", (ctx) => {
    let input = ctx.message.text;
    
    let inputArray = input.split("#");
    
    console.log(inputArray);
    
    let message = "";

    inputArray.shift();  
    message = inputArray.join(" ");
        
    let messageArray =  message.split("/");
    console.log(messageArray);

    for(let index = 0; message[index] != '/'; index++ )
    {
        ctx.reply("/ta " + message[index]);
    }
    return null 
})
```

So if I take   this signal

```
"Long/Buy #EOS/USDT ️ 
Entry Point - 14.135
Targets: 14.190 - 14.250
Leverage - 10x
Stop Loss - 13.430
```

All I should get is  "EOS"

unfortunately this code does filter correcly, but every letter succeeds after a new line, and the secodn time I input it, I get the letter sequence messed up.. like

```
E
S
O
```

I've read about adding  `,end=''`  to the letter, but I don't know how to integrate it in an array

Comment: `end=''` is Python, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`message` is a string, so iterating over `message[index]` will iterate each character until it reaches the `/`.. so the output you are getting makes total sense. I'm not sure why you're doing that, though, since you already have the string "EOS" in your `messageArray[0]`. Is there a reason you're not just outputting that?

Comment: nope... I guess I overcomplicated it thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `ctx.reply()` separately for each letter before `/`.

Just get the substring before `/` and send it as a single message. Since you just split `message` using `/`, the message you want is the first element of that array.

```js
let messageArray = message.split("/");
console.log(messageArray);

ctx.reply(`/ts ${messageArray[0]}`);
```

Comment: should be `${...}`, not just `{...}`

Comment: I keep going back and forth between JS and Python questions and getting the syntax mixed up there.

Comment: I figured as much, just wanted to make sure you caught it without me editing your answer